# Convert Number to Date or Date to Number

Tags: sql, database, oracle, type-conversion

```
Select  a.APPL_NBR, b.APPL_NBR, a. APPL_RCVD_DATE, b.INITDATE
From DW_ODS.N_APP_DECHIST a
Join EDW_WDS.D_APP_INFO b
On a.APPL_NBR=b.APPL_NBR
Where a. APPL_RCVD_DATE != b.INITDATE
order by a. APPL_RCVD_DATE
```

I'm getting  this error "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes" I don't know how to convert numbers to date (I'm a QA Engineer and my SQL knowledge is limited)

APPL_RCVD_DATE: Data type Number
INITDATE: Data Type Date

Can someone give me a hand about how to convert from numbers to data or vice-versa?

Comment: What does your actual data look like?  A `NUMBER` representing a date might be a number of days from a fixed date (different systems use different fixed dates), it could be a Unix timestamp, it could be a number in the format YYYYMMDD it could be something else.

Comment: Hi Justin, It looks like this 19970825

Comment: You need to use to_date function in your where clause, like `Where b.INITDATE != TO_DATE(a. APPL_RCVD_DATE,'YYYYMMDD')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TO_DATE` to convert strings into dates, and `TO_CHAR` to convert dates into strings. See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51063) for details of the format masks you can use.

Eg.

```
select to_date('01012015', 'ddmmyyyy'), to_char(sysdate, 'fmDay Month yyyy')
from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer for how do I integrate that to the query I'm running ? Like a said my knowledge in SQL is quite basic

Comment: you'd need to convert the column that has a date-as-number into a date, so the `to_date()` would need to go around that column wherever you're comparing it to the date column. E.g. `where to_date(date_as_num_col, 'ddmmyyyy') = date_col`. You'll obviously have to amend the format mask depending on how your number is made up.